# System programming with php

Tags: php, windows, scheduling

I need a idea to open a browser automatically with an login URL as i start my pc(windows XP) using PHP script.How can i schedule the tasks or else please help

Comment: Why would you need PHP to do this? Just add a link to your login URL to the autostart menu

Comment: i need every thing programatically.like i install a php code on my system and it will do the tasks as i mentioned above.

Comment: Sounds like a "Use the right tool for the right job" is necessary. ;-)

Comment: Well maybe he already has a working script and just wants to run it at startup.

Answer (score 3):

On windows:

- Make sure PHP is installed properly,
  or dowload and install it.
- Go to the PHP directorly and create a new shortcut to php.exe
- Open the new shortcuts propertys (rightclick)
- add " -f " and the path tp your script to the shortcut
- copy the shortcut into your autostart directory